# Android: creating a layout that goes beyond screen width

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I need to create a layout like the image below. The blue rectangle in the image represents the screen.

Creating a layout with 4 images is easy, the simpelest way is probably with vertical and horizontal LinearLayouts.
But i don't have a clue how i can go beyond the screenwidth for panning reasons

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not the best solution but since you would like to design outside the screen borders one option would be to use a RelativeLayout for instance and then assign negative margins for the left-side pictures.